# How can I get 3 names to repeat for every date in a date range?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my first question here so I apologize if I do something wrong. I am also an SQL amateur so sorry if i don't make any sense. I am working with SQL Server 2014.

I have dates in a date range (11/01/15 to 11/30/15) and I have 3 location names : NY, LA, SF. Can I get each of those names to show up in a seperate row for each date in the range?

Something like this:

11/01/15 | NY
11/01/15 | LA
11/01/15 | SF
11/02/15 | NY
11/02/15 | LA
11/02/15 | SF
11/03/15 | NY
11/03/15 | LA
11/03/15 | SF
.
.
.
.
11/30/15 | NY
11/30/15 | LA
11/30/15 | SF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your CTE:

```
WITH mycte
     AS
        (
     SELECT CAST('20151101' AS DATETIME
                ) DateValue
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DateValue + 1
     FROM mycte
     WHERE DateValue + 1 < '20151201'
        ),
     myNames
            (myName
            )
     AS
        (
     SELECT 'NY'
     UNION
     SELECT 'LA'
     UNION
     SELECT 'SF'
        )
     SELECT *
     FROM mycte m
          CROSS JOIN myNames mn;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming dates are in a table called myDates and names are in a table called myNames with fieldnames myDate and myName respectively:

```
select d.myDate, n.myName
from myDates d
cross join myNames n
where d.MyDate >= '20151101' and d.myDate < '20151201'
```

Comment: Yes the dates come from this query : 

WITH mycte AS
   (
    SELECT CAST('2015-11-01' AS DATETIME) DateValue
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DateValue + 1
    FROM    mycte   
    WHERE   DateValue + 1 < '2015-11-30'
   )

Comment: Never ever use yyyy-MM-dd style for date/datetimes. It doesnt work right with SQL server and is dependant on language settings. Instead, if you have to use a string, then only use ODBC canonical format (yyyyMMdd). ie: cast('20151101' as datetime).

Comment: I actually got that query from a question on this website. Could you suggest a better option? Is it simply to change it to mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: Check my samples. They correctly have 'yyyyMMdd'. Your CTE based query is one of the ways to create a "tally" table,

Comment: Yeah. I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20150111'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '20151130'
DECLARE @Diff INT = DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)
PRINT @Diff

;WITH DateRangeCte AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, currDay - 1, @StartDate) AS RangeDate
    FROM ( 
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS currDay
        -- this table should have more records than range size
        FROM sys.messages                               
    ) nbrs
    WHERE currDay - 1 <= @Diff
)
SELECT RangeDate, LocationName
FROM DateRangeCte C 
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 'NY' AS LocationName UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'LA' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'SF'
    ) Loc
go
```

As suggested, `DateRangeCte` can be generated using a [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) or by iterating through a "big enough" table (number of rows is known to be larger than interval size). I have chosen sys.message since it is quite big (more than 200K), but it will have an impact upon performance. If performance is important, choose recursive CTE (`st33vemcqu33n's` answer).

Also, I have CROSS JOINed with an "anonymous" table. I guess those states will be stored in a persistent table, so you will cross join with that table.

Comment: interesting, you have a variable `@Diff` you never use.

Comment: Yes, I have fixed that. Thank for pointing out. Anyway, Cetin Basoz's solution is more elegant :)